# XCode Error, unable to see a difference

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

Alright, I'm reading the Aaron Hillegass book for Cocoa Programming, on the drag and drop chapter. I was following along with one of the lessons, and I typically change variable names as I find it keeps me a little more engaged and gives me a better understanding. I started getting this error, though:

```
2010-10-04 00:38:06.699 TypingTutor[421:a0f] -[BigLetterView dragImage:at:offset:event:pasteboard:source:slideback:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100424390
```

Now, I figured it was because I'd messed up some variable name so I went back and copied the variables directly from the book and still got the error. XCode was saying the following function might not get a response. Well, regardless I could not figure it out for the life of me, so I scrapped the function and redid it. What drives me crazy is that it worked the second time, but I did notice a difference in that XCode highlighted the syntax of the function that works, but didn't for the one that doesn't. I can see no physical difference and am stumped as to why one is different than the other. Both were typed in on a Mac keyboard, so I can't see it being some hidden character due to encoding, but yeah, I'm just hoping I'm missing something extremely obvious because it's 1 AM... has anyone ever run into this before?

Methods copied directly from .m file...

### This one works

```
 [self dragImage:anImage
     at:p
    offset:NSMakeSize(0,0)
     event:mouseDownEvent
   pasteboard:pb
    source:self
slideBack:YES];
```

### This one doesn't

```
 [self dragImage:anImage
     at:p
    offset:NSMakeSize(0,0)
     event:mouseDownEvent
   pasteboard:pb
    source:self
    slideback:YES];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objective-C is case sensitive, so method names with different cases in their letters are considered different methods. The one that works, "slideback" is written `slideBack` with a capital B, which is probably what you're calling. The one that doesn't has a lowercase 'b' and is written `slideback`. In Objective-C, those are different methods. The definition is obviously written with the uppercase 'B', which is why that one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Alright, so it was just the late night, I guess when I can't tell the difference between lowercase and uppercase b it's time to call it a night... I'll accept this once it lets me...

Comment: @thyrgle: It was formatted as XCode aligns it, with the semicolons in a line, but I think that pushed `pasteboard:` too far to the left and broke the formatting, so it messed everything else up...

Comment: @Robert: No, I was just stating that I kept thinking: "How could an indent cause an error?" when the whole problem was your capitalization.

Comment: Oh, yeah lol. I tried everything... except the proper function name, but hey.

Comment: @thyrgle: I thought that was some hidden portal reference, I was trying to figure out what it meant lol; the cake def /is/ a lie tho.

Comment: @Robert: if Xcode doesn't highlight your method name (syntax color it), or it warns you, it's almost 99% guaranteed that you have a typo or misspelling in your method name, so check that first!